# React - show / hide for text pairs in iteration always shows all text instead of selected element - why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, show-hide

I am iterating through corresponding questions / answers, when I click on a particular question, I want to show the answer/and hide it when I click on the same question again. I change the class from hide to show (onclick) of the particular answer. However, on click ALL questions/answers are being shown or hidden. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import messages from "./messages.js";

class Faq extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {show: false};
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            show: !this.state.show
        });
    }

    render() {
        const qa = messages.faqs.category1.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <p className="App-intro">
                        <button className="question" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>{item.question}</button>
                    </p>
                    <p className={!this.state.show ? 'hidden' : 'show'}>{item.answer}</p>

                </div>
            )
        });

        return (
            <div className="App">
                {qa}
            </div>
        );
    }
}   
export default Faq;
```

questions/answers object/array:

```
export default {
    "faqs": {
        "category 1": [
            {
                "question": "question 1?",
                "answer": "answer 1",
            },
            {
                "question": "question 2?",
                "answer": "answer 2",
            },
            {
                "question": "question 3?",
                "answer": "answer 3",
            }
        ]
        // ...category 2 etc
    }
}
```

css:

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: The variable `show` is not linked to a question but this is a global variable

Comment: Thanks. How do I link it?

Comment: You'll have to structure it in a way where each question has it's own show/hide variable associated with it. You could track that in this FAQ component, but I think a simpler way would be to create a new component for questions and that component would have a boolean in its state to determine whether it's hidden or not.

Comment: @2018code2018 Your objects should be like `{"question": "question 1?","answer": "answer 1", "show": true}`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with classnames, you can render/not render that element like so:

```
{
    this.state.show && <p>{item.answer}</p>
}
```

You put that in one of your divs in your render function. There are some additional things you should change with your code. But this will get you started. Note that the state is going to apply to all your questions, so you might want to add additional complexity, such as a show state for each individual question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way.

Lets assume your question and answer is in pair.
Make a component of one pair and assign a state  for toggle. Then iterate this component to length of your number of questions. So you will have no of component same as question dynamically and each will be have its own state.